# Get-PnPMicrosoft365GroupOwners returning PnP.PowerShell.Commands.Model.Microsoft365User instead of owner names

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, pnp-powershell, office-365-groups, sharepoint-admin-center

Here is the code I am running.  I am able to get groupIds, but when using the Get-PnPMicrosoft365GroupOwners, the owners are displayed as PnP.PowerShell.Commands.Model.Microsoft365User.  I will attach the code I am using.

```
    #Connect to Admin Center
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $TenantAdminURL -Credentials $Cred

#Get sites, filter out irrelevant sites
$SiteCollections = Get-PnPTenantSite -Filter "Url -like $TenantSiteBaseURL -and Url -notlike '-my.sharepoint.com/' -and Url -notlike '/portals/'" | ForEach-Object { Get-PnPTenantSite -Url $_.Url | select Title,Url,GroupId,Owner }
$SiteCollections

ForEach ($Site in $SiteCollections){ 
   
    #If site has a group
    if ($Site.GroupId -ne "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"){
        
        #Get group owners using groupId
        $Owners = Get-PnPMicrosoft365GroupOwners -Identity $Site.GroupId
        Write-Host $Owners
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a Owner object, and not accessing the properties.  Here is how I fixed it.

```
$Group = Get-PnPMicrosoft365Group -Identity $Site.GroupId -IncludeOwners
$Emails = ($Group.Owners | Select Email)
```